# Integral of a hyperbolic function

Tags: calculus, integration, hyperbolic-functions

> $$\int \tanh(x) - \tanh^3(x)\,dx$$

I get the answer as $\tanh x + c$?

I took out a factor of $\tanh x$, used the identity $1-\tanh^2 x=\text{sech}^2x$, used the substitution of $u=\tanh x$,

and reduced the question to $\int 1 du$.

Is this the way you would normally approach this question?

Cheers.

Gurjinder.B

Comment: Using the hyperbolic identity and your substitution gives that the integral is $\int \tanh x \operatorname{sech}^2 x \,dx = \int u \,du$, not $\int \,du$.

Comment: Yes it does, sorry, the insert should be $frac1/2tanh^2x+c$ , right?

Comment: That looks good to me.

Comment: Check your substitutions:  You should get $-\frac{1}{2} \text{sech}^2(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The derivative of $f(x)=\tanh x$ is
$$
f'(x)=\frac{\cosh^2x-\sinh^2x}{\cosh^2x}=1-\tanh^2x
$$
so the integral is
$$
\int f(x)f'(x)\,dx=\frac{1}{2}(f(x))^2+c=\frac{1}{2}\tanh^2x+c
$$